# For what "finger" getActionIndex and getActionMasked refer to?

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out all the multi - touch event handling in android for couple of hours and I just don't get it.

If I have multi touch event MotionEvent stores all fingers data right?

Say I touch the screen with 3 fingers simultaneously or move 2 fingers on the screen simultaneously when asking  getActionIndex or ( getActionMasked ) I get one result but as I move or ( touch the screen with 3 fingers ) so   how do I know for which finger getActionIndex or ( getActionMasked ) refers to?

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

ID is used to identify and track pointers (let just say pointer is your finger). While index for a particular touch gesture might change (you might lift the finger etc) but id remains the same (thus used for tracking gestures).

```
int pointerCount = m.getPointerCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++)
    {
        int x = (int) m.getX(i);
        int y = (int) m.getY(i);            
        int id = m.getPointerId(i);
        if(id==0) {
            ...First touch....
}

........
```

I am also new to android development. Was reading about multi touch yesterday. Hope this helps.